# What algorithms are used for force dispersal between rigid objects attached by joints?

Tags: algorithm, physics

I have in mind a 2d, side-scrolling game which requires the construction of vehicles and/or structures built of conjoined rigid structures, like beams or platforms.  These structures will be impacted from various angles.

What algorithms and data structures are used typically in, say, bridge-building games, to determine the force dispersal between such attached, rigid objects, and at what point the joints bend or break?

Comment: World of Goo also handles algorithms similar to what I'm looking for.

Comment: Check out mass spring systems.

Comment: Are you using box2d?

Comment: If you use a nice library (like box2d) all that stuff is built into the physics and you just have to program the logic for coordinating the joints/fixtures and forces. It's a great library, popular on pc and android (I'm pretty sure). It was written in c/c++ but has also been translated into java

Comment: A good suggestion.  I was considering [box2d](http://box2d-js.sourceforge.net/) or [matter.js](http://brm.io/matter-js/) for interactions between larger objects, but the stress-bearing interiors may potentially bear thousands of connections, each.  Writing said stress algorithms myself would be the only way to precisely optimize the balance between accuracy and speed.  The force dispersal algorithms in bridge-building games would be a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are content with equilibrium cases (just finding distribution of forces in a static structure, possibly detecting destructive overload), and all your structures are discrete (e.g., built from trusses not cast from iron), and all your joints are pins (cannot support torque, so you only solve for forces), then you can use [the method of joints](http://www.ce.memphis.edu/3121/notes/notes_03b.pdf).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_analysis discusses both the method of joints and the method of sections.

If your structures are even more regular (e.g., built from axis-aligned trusses), then it is possible to optimize algorithm even more.